# Sort Elasticsearch terms aggregation by child terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I maintain a large web application where users can vote on images.

To help fight against fraudulent voting by users, I have some vote data loaded in Elasticsearch, indexed by vote direction, image ID, user ID, and IP. I'd like to be able to aggregate votes by IP, then by image (posting in this case), then by cardinality of user ID.

I'd like the images that have the largest amount of users voting under the same IP to come to the top of the topmost terms aggregation. Unfortunately, trying to sort the parent terms aggregation by that maximum value doesn't work.

```
:size: 0
:aggs:
  :ip_votes:
    :terms:
      :field: ip
      :order:
        images>users.value.max: desc # <- doesn't work
    :aggs:
      :images:
        :terms:
          :field: image_id
          :order:
            users.value: desc
        :aggs:
          :users:
            :cardinality:
              :field: user_id
```

Running this aggregation gives a generic error:

> Invalid terms aggregation order path [images>users.value.max]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end. Sub-path [images] points to non single-bucket aggregation.

How can I go about accomplishing this, if it can't be done directly?

Mapping for the collection:

```
vote_stats:
  mappings:
    vote_stat:
      dynamic: "false"
      _all:
        enabled: false
      properties:
        created_at:
          type: "date"
        downvotes:
          type: "integer"
        image_id:
          type: "integer"
        ip:
          type: "ip"
        tag_ids:
          type: "integer"
        time_offset:
          type: "date"
        upvotes:
          type: "integer"
        user_id:
          type: "integer"
```

Comment: yeah i doubt if sort will work. can you add your json mappings ?

Comment: @user3775217 added